# Auto fit row within Excel VBscript code

Tags: excel, row, vba

I am using the command

```
.Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

to autofit the columns in my excel vbscript after I run my loop, however I am getting an error when I place the command:

```
Rows(xCount).EntireRow.AutoFit
```

to auto height fit the rows in the sheet.

Can you tell me how to autofit all the rows in my spreadsheet?

Here is my full code:

```
Sub SearchFolders()
'UpdatebySUPERtoolsforExcel2016
    Dim xFso As Object
    Dim xFld As Object
    Dim xUpdate As Boolean
    Dim xCount As Long
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Set xFileDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xFileDialog.AllowMultiSelect = False
    xFileDialog.Title = "Select a forlder"
    If xFileDialog.Show = -1 Then
        xStrPath = xFileDialog.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
    If xStrPath = "" Then Exit Sub
    xStrSearch = "failed"
    xUpdate = Application.ScreenUpdating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xOut = wsReport
    xRow = 1
    With xOut
        .Cells(xRow, 1) = "Workbook"
        .Cells(xRow, 2) = "Worksheet"
        .Cells(xRow, 8) = "Unit"
        .Cells(xRow, 9) = "Status"
        Set xFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set xFld = xFso.GetFolder(xStrPath)
        xStrFile = Dir(xStrPath & "\*.xlsx")
        Do While xStrFile <> ""
            Set xWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=xStrPath & "\" & xStrFile, UpdateLinks:=0, ReadOnly:=True, AddToMRU:=False)
            For Each xWk In xWb.Worksheets
                Set xFound = xWk.UsedRange.Find(xStrSearch, LookIn:=xlValues)
                If Not xFound Is Nothing Then
                    xStrAddress = xFound.Address
                End If
                Do
                    If xFound Is Nothing Then
                        Exit Do
                    Else

                        xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 3) = xFound.Address
                        WriteDetails rCellwsReport, xFound

                    End If
                    Set xFound = xWk.Cells.FindNext(After:=xFound)
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Rows(xCount).EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With

    MsgBox xCount & "cells have been found", , "SUPERtools for Excel"
ExitHandler:
    Set xOut = Nothing


    Application.ScreenUpdating = xUpdate
    Exit Sub
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation
    Resume ExitHandler
End Sub

Private Sub WriteDetails(ByRef xReceiver As Range, ByRef xDonor As Range)
  xReceiver.Value = xDonor.Parent.Name
  xReceiver.Offset(, 1).Value = xDonor.Address

  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  ' Copy the row of the Donor to the receiver starting from column D.
  ' Since you want to preserve formats, we use the .Copy method
    xDonor.EntireRow.Resize(, 100).Copy xReceiver.Offset(, 2)
  ''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
  Set xReceiver = xReceiver.Offset(1)

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have merged cells?

Comment: no merged cells.   Thanks.

Comment: `.rows(xCount)` refers to a single row. You will need something like `.Range("A1:A" & xCount). Rows.EntireRow.AutoFit`. Sorry - I'm not in a spot to test this.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Are you missing the preceding **.** ?

`Rows(xCount).EntireRow.AutoFit` should be `.Rows(xCount).EntireRow.AutoFit`

Comment: I am running a loop using xcount, here is a snippet of my code: `xCount = xCount + 1
                        xRow = xRow + 1
                        .Cells(xRow, 1) = xWb.Name
                        .Cells(xRow, 2) = xWk.Name
                   End If
                Loop While xStrAddress <> xFound.Address
            Next
            xWb.Close (False)
            xStrFile = Dir
        Loop
        .Columns("A:I").EntireColumn.AutoFit
        .Rows(xCount).EntireRow.AutoFit
    End With`  If I try your solution, it appears only the 2nd to last row is correctly autofit.

Comment: I can't really tell what you're trying to achieve with the above code snippet - can you edit your original post to include this as properly formatted section of code

Comment: If you look at the OP's full code he is not missing the preceding .

The issue is that xCount is a Long where a Range is required. @OldUgly got it right in his comment